# Stream music from Ubuntu One to several phones?

Tags: ubuntu-one, music, android, streaming

I am about to buy an Android-phone to myself and another one for my son. The "killing application" is this offer form Ubuntu one: "Music Streaming Enjoy your music anywhere and get 20GB of storage for just $3.99 per month". I just need to know:

With such a deal, can I use two (or more) phones?

Best,
Lars

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we're not enforcing number of concurrent clients at the moment. If we ever do, you would certainly be able to use 2 devices at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

if you and your son are willing to use a single ubuntu one account and thus **have the same music library (and also share all shared files)** then you should be...
else you will have to pay 3.99 for yourself and your son...

do note that **you still need to pay your mobile provider** for all data transferred, so a good data plan is still advised (unless you sync a long play queue while on WiFi, which is also an option).